# R, data.table, rolling join not matching nearest value

Tags: r, join, merge, data.table

I'm by no means an R expert, any help is very much appreciated!

I have two data.tables. The examples below only include (part of) the first trial from the first block for a single team, the actual data has multiple teams, blocks and trials. The 'time' column always begins at 0 for each trial.
The full eyeDatP1 and eyeDatP2 tables can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/Rf0AmWhg) and [here](https://pastebin.com/S9PmjYUG)

'eyeDatP1':

```
+--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
| "team" | "block" | "trial" | "x.pos1" | "y.pos1" |       "time"       |      "time1"       | "condition" |
+--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
|    910 |       1 |       1 |    7.012 |   19.034 |                  0 |                  0 | "normal"    |
|    910 |       1 |       1 |   13.342 |  134.199 | 0.0900001525878906 | 0.0900001525878906 | "normal"    |
|    910 |       1 |       1 |   18.525 |  127.041 |  0.180000066757202 |  0.180000066757202 | "normal"    |
|    910 |       1 |       1 |   16.098 |  119.385 |  0.279999971389771 |  0.279999971389771 | "normal"    |
|    910 |       1 |       1 |   17.218 |  118.263 |  0.370000123977661 |  0.370000123977661 | "normal"    |
|    910 |       1 |       1 |   18.385 |  116.526 |  0.470000028610229 |  0.470000028610229 | "normal"    |
+--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

and 'eyeDatP2':

```
+--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+
| "team" | "block" | "trial" | "x.pos2" | "y.pos2" |      "time"       |      "time2"      | "condition" |
+--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+
|    910 |       1 |       1 |   72.656 | -136.216 |                 0 |                 0 | "normal"    |
|    910 |       1 |       1 |   71.398 | -139.887 | 0.070000171661377 | 0.070000171661377 | "normal"    |
|    910 |       1 |       1 |   68.219 | -146.002 | 0.170000076293945 | 0.170000076293945 | "normal"    |
|    910 |       1 |       1 | -166.067 |  125.859 | 0.259999990463257 | 0.259999990463257 | "normal"    |
|    910 |       1 |       1 | -164.175 |  112.627 | 0.360000133514404 | 0.360000133514404 | "normal"    |
|    910 |       1 |       1 |   27.089 |   96.251 | 0.450000047683716 | 0.450000047683716 | "normal"    |
+--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+
```

I want to join these two tables via the closest timestamp (joining via the 'time' column).

#### EDIT

How I've ended up trying to get this to work (it still doesn't) is rather convuluted and uses a heap of loops so... apologies in advance. Heres what I've got:

```
# Prepare empty df for merging
eyeDat <- data.frame(team = numeric(),
                     block = numeric(),
                     trial = numeric(),
                     x.pos1 = numeric(),
                     y.pos1 = numeric(),
                     time = numeric(),
                     time1 = numeric(),
                     condition = numeric(),
                     time.match = numeric(),
                     i.team = numeric(),
                     i.block = numeric(),
                     i.trial = numeric(),
                     x.pos2 = numeric(),
                     y.pos2 = numeric(),
                     i.time = numeric(),
                     time2 = numeric(),
                     i.condition = numeric())

# Some timestamps are identical, only keep the first of these
eyeDatP1 <- eyeDatP1[!duplicated(eyeDatP1[,c("team", "block", "trial", "time")]),]
eyeDatP2 <- eyeDatP2[!duplicated(eyeDatP2[,c("team", "block", "trial", "time")]),]

# Change the 'time' column, such that the trial begins at time 0
# then merge at the trial level
for (team.num in unique(eyeDatP1$team)) { # separate at team level
  temp1P1 <- subset(eyeDatP1, eyeDatP1$team == team.num)
  temp1P2 <- subset(eyeDatP2, eyeDatP2$team == team.num)
  for (condition.num in unique(temp1P1$condition)) { # separate at condition level
    temp2P1 <- subset(temp1P1, temp1P1$condition == condition.num)
    temp2P2 <- subset(temp1P2, temp1P2$condition == condition.num)
    for (trial.num in unique(temp2P1$trial)) { # separate at trial level
      temp3P1 <- subset(temp2P1, temp2P1$trial == trial.num)
      temp3P1$time1 <- temp3P1$time - temp3P1$time[1] # subtract the starting time (of trial) from all timestamps (for that trial)
      
      temp3P2 <- subset(temp2P2, temp2P2$trial == trial.num)
      temp3P2$time2 <- temp3P2$time - temp3P2$time[1] # subtract the starting time (of trial) from all timestamps (for that trial)
      
      temp3P1$time.match <- temp3P1$time1
      temp3P2$time.match <- temp3P2$time2
      
      # Merge by closest timestamp
      temp3P1 <- setDT(temp3P1)
      temp3P2 <- setDT(temp3P2)
      setkey(temp3P1, time.match)
      setkey(temp3P2, time.match)
      temp3 <- temp3P1[temp3P2, roll = "nearest"]
      
      eyeDat <- rbind(eyeDat, temp3)
    }
  }
}
```

The above gives me some really large gaps between the 'matched' time stamps

```
eyeDat$time.diff <- eyeDat$time2 - eyeDat$time1
eyeDat <- subset(eyeDat, !is.na(eyeDat$time.diff))
bad <- subset(eyeDat, eyeDat$time.diff >= 1 | eyeDat$time.diff <= -1)
```

This outputs data.frame 'bad', below is the last n number of rows from 'bad':

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  "team" "block" "trial" "x.pos1" "y.pos1" "time" "time1" "condition" "time.match" "i.team" "i.block" "i.trial" "x.pos2" "y.pos2" "i.time" "time2" "i.condition" "time.diff"   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.2599999904633 910 2 69 -168.622 -21.305 1499754632.32 28.2599999904633 "individual" 6.35000014305115 |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.2699999809265 910 2 69 -167.567 -19.674 1499754632.33 28.2699999809265 "individual" 6.3600001335144  |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.2799999713898 910 2 69 -167.567 -19.674 1499754632.34 28.2799999713898 "individual" 6.37000012397766 |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.289999961853 910 2 69 -166.493 -17.976 1499754632.35 28.289999961853 "individual" 6.38000011444092   |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.2999999523163 910 2 69 -164.281 -17.984 1499754632.36 28.2999999523163 "individual" 6.39000010490417 |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.3099999427795 910 2 69 -164.281 -17.984 1499754632.37 28.3099999427795 "individual" 6.40000009536743 |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.3200001716614 910 2 69 -162.836 -16.612 1499754632.38 28.3200001716614 "individual" 6.41000032424927 |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.3300001621246 910 2 69 -163.784 -15.401 1499754632.39 28.3300001621246 "individual" 6.42000031471252 |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.3400001525879 910 2 69 -163.784 -15.401 1499754632.4 28.3400001525879 "individual" 6.43000030517578  |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.3500001430511 910 2 69 -164.593 -14.366 1499754632.41 28.3500001430511 "individual" 6.44000029563904 |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.3600001335144 910 2 69 -164.593 -14.366 1499754632.42 28.3600001335144 "individual" 6.45000028610229 |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.3700001239777 910 2 69 -165.06 -13.378 1499754632.43 28.3700001239777 "individual" 6.46000027656555  |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.3800001144409 910 2 69 -165.06 -13.378 1499754632.44 28.3800001144409 "individual" 6.47000026702881  |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.3900001049042 910 2 69 -165.737 -14.238 1499754632.45 28.3900001049042 "individual" 6.48000025749207 |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.4000000953674 910 2 69 -166.492 -15.478 1499754632.46 28.4000000953674 "individual" 6.49000024795532 |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.4100000858307 910 2 69 -166.492 -15.478 1499754632.47 28.4100000858307 "individual" 6.50000023841858 |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.4200000762939 910 2 69 -165.439 -17.974 1499754632.48 28.4200000762939 "individual" 6.51000022888184 |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.4300000667572 910 2 69 -165.439 -17.974 1499754632.49 28.4300000667572 "individual" 6.52000021934509 |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.4400000572205 910 2 69 -164.605 -19.655 1499754632.5 28.4400000572205 "individual" 6.53000020980835  |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.4500000476837 910 2 69 -163.724 -20.565 1499754632.51 28.4500000476837 "individual" 6.54000020027161 |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.460000038147 910 2 69 -163.724 -20.565 1499754632.52 28.460000038147 "individual" 6.55000019073486   |
| 910 2 69 413.955 -392.938 1499754525.32 21.9099998474121 "individual" 28.4700000286102 910 2 69 -163.435 -23.499 1499754632.53 28.4700000286102 "individual" 6.56000018119812 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
eyeDatP1 <- fread("eyedatp1.txt")
eyeDatP2 <- fread("eyedatp2.txt")

#Setting keys only on the variable to be used for the 'join'
setkey(eyeDatP1,time)
setkey(eyeDatP2,time)

eyeDat  <- eyeDatP1[eyeDatP2, roll = "nearest"]
```

Comment: For some reason, the further in to the join you get, the further the gap between the matched timestamps. Do you have any idea why this might be occurring? I've edited my question to reflect the method I'm currently employing to try to match via timestamp